# Remove completed downloads from rutorrent

Tags: scripts, cron, bittorrent, rtorrent, rutorrent

I just set up rutorrent after being a long time rtorrent user.
I want to remove the completed downloads. When I use a `.torrent` file i just have `.rtorrent.rc` remove the file and `rtorrent` removes it from the list.

Now that I have rutorrent, I can use rss to download files. But there is no tied file.

How do I remove completed downloads from `rtorrent/rutorrent` if they don't have a tied file, using a script?

I have tried a script the runs

```
rtcontrol --from-view started is_complete=yes --delete --yes
```

but nothing seems to happen.

Edit:
When I run it as root I get:

```
root@linux:/home/usr1# ./bin/removeCompleted.sh
WARNING:pyrocore.util.load_config.ConfigLoader:Configuration file '/root/.pyroscope/config.ini' not found, use the command 'pyroadmin --create-config' to create it!
WARNING:pyrocore.util.load_config.ConfigLoader:Configuration file '/root/.pyroscope/config.py' not found!
ERROR:pyrocore.scripts.rtcontrol.RtorrentControl:Config file '/root/.rtorrent.rc' doesn't exist!
INFO:pyrocore.scripts.rtcontrol.RtorrentControl:Total time: 0.035 seconds.
```

`.rtorrent.rc` calls a python script that I wrote that calls `removeCompleted.sh` with `os.system("/home/usr1/bin/removeCompleted.sh > logfile.log")`. The log file comes back empty. If I Call `removeCompleted.sh` directly form `.rtorrent.rc` then rtorrent freezes and I need to reboot the PC.

Comment: "Nothing" is highly unlikely, either there is some output or an error message.

Comment: ok, then I need a little help with finding the log.

Comment: a) running from root makes no sense at all, b) if you start rtcontrol from rtorrent, then use --detach, else you create a deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `rtcontrol` from an event handler or some method definition, either use the `--detach` option, or some form of `execute.bg=` (the latter especially if you call `rtcontrol` indirectly via a shell script).

BTW, this applies to any kind of code that you run from `rtorrent` and then in turn calls back to `rtorrent` via XML-RPC.